# Framework7 Vue : Get current view params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-framework-7

I was wondering about **getting current view params** in the right way on **Framework7 Vue**.

```
this.$f7route.params
```

This is not useable when I am using `<f7-view>` because of history or pushState with duplicate components (this will return each of their own params)

So the question is **how to get current view (page) parameters?** (inside components)

Answer (score 0):

**Gotcha!**

```
const currentParams = { ...this.$f7route.params } // or JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( this.$f7route.params ))
// currentParams.name
```